# SSAS Cube - Obscure low numbers

Tags: ssas, mdx, cubes

I have a business requirement to Obscure low numbers for Confidentiality.

I have been trying to do this using a hidden measure and a calculation.  The hidden measure is named 'Encounters_Count' and the MDX I'm using for the calculation is:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Number of Encounters]
    AS IIF( [Measures].[Encounters_Count] <= 5, "<hidden>", [Measures].[Encounters_Count] ),
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0", NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Encounters_Count] }, VISIBLE = 1;
```

This works except that in some cases it's possible to work out the hidden numbers from the group totals.

I've tried to write a recursive Calculation using IsLeaf() to exclude "<hidden>" results from the total by applying different rules depending on if it's the parent or child but I can't work out how to do this correctly.

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
...
IIF( IsLeaf( [Measures].[Encounters_Count] ),
    IIF( [Measures].[Encounters_Count] <= 5, "<hidden>", [Measures].[Encounters_Count] ),
    SUM( IIF( [Measures].[Number of Encounters] <> "<hidden>", [Measures].[Number of Encounters], NULL ) )
),
...
```

**Edit:** Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to avoid, in this case you can work out that the <hidden> number is 4. It would be preferable for the Grand Total to show 31,163 as that is the total of the Visible numbers.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: I'm new to SSAS and have been thrown in at the deep end, I've searched google and tried multiple methods with no avail.

Comment: `IsLeaf` will always return true for a measure, as the measure itself is at the bottom level of the `Measures` hierarchy, which happens to have one level only.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, what you need is that if either the number is low, or if it is close to the total, you have to hide it.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Number of Encounters] AS
    IIF( ([Measures].[Encounters_Count] <> 0 AND [Measures].[Encounters_Count] <= 5)
      OR (    ([Measures].[Encounters_Count], [Dim1].[Hier1].[All]) - [Measures].[Encounters_Count] > 0
          AND ([Measures].[Encounters_Count], [Dim1].[Hier1].[All]) - [Measures].[Encounters_Count] <= 5)
      OR (    ([Measures].[Encounters_Count], [Dim1].[Hier2].[All]) - [Measures].[Encounters_Count] > 0
          AND ([Measures].[Encounters_Count], [Dim1].[Hier2].[All]) - [Measures].[Encounters_Count] <= 5)
      OR (    ([Measures].[Encounters_Count], [Dim2].[Hier1].[All]) - [Measures].[Encounters_Count] > 0
          AND ([Measures].[Encounters_Count], [Dim2].[Hier1].[All]) - [Measures].[Encounters_Count] <= 5)
      OR // add all 'All' members of all hierarchies here
       , "<hidden>", [Measures].[Encounters_Count] ),
    FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0", NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Encounters_Count] }, VISIBLE = 1;
```

would hide these. It is a rather long statement, and needs careful maintenance as soon as you change any hierarchies in the cube.

For a perfect solution, also combinations of more than one `All` member would have to be treated, but this can lead to a [combinatorial explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion), and I am not sure if you can get these combinations with standard client tools that do not allow you to write your own MDX. But - to be honest - I did not think much about that.

Potentially, you would want to use `Abs()` around the values to avoid issues with negative numbers if they could appear.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I've updated the question to better show what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The definition that I propose would not show the value of the "Other" column, as it has a difference of less than 5 to the "All" member, shown by Excel with the column title "Grand Total". Have you tried it? You just need to use those hierarchies that you use in the test query for testing, not all that are in the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start hiding numbers and fiddling with totals, the report becomes less accurate...so... if your business users are saying they are happy with inaccuracy, why not think of other ways to achieve your goal (before thinking of MDX)?

You could add 5% to all totals / replace the right-most digit with "8" / round up to the nearest 100...

Do this to all totals, and you MDX doesn't have to worry about IsLeaf() or whether some of the totals have hidden values within them and some don't.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Obscured Values] AS
IIF([Measures].[Encounters_Count] <= 5, "<hidden>", 
  IIF([Measures].[Encounters_Count] > 100, VBA!round([Measures].[Encounters_Count]*1.1, 0), [Measures].[Encounters_Count])
)
```

Comment: Maybe if I elaborate on the reason for obscuring low numbers.  Some of the data we deal with is sensitive data.  Low numbers could allow the people behind the data to be identified which would be a breach of confidentiality. If the dimensions being used could identify people rather then giving an overview the data should be hidden.

Comment: I understand. But if you are going to change the numbers in some of the totals, I thought perhaps it wouldn't matter if you subtly altered all totals by a random amount. This could still give a good overview (e.g. Total for A is 200-ish compared to total for B which is 1000-ish). Just an idea. Sorry I can't help with the MDX.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it acceptable to make the original measure invisible and creating another measure to show the values and secure/suppress it when needed. This way cube can aggregate/calculate things as usual.

Comment: If you know of a way to possibly secure or suppress the measure that might work.  The main issue with some other solutions offered is I won't know what dimension combinations are going to be used by the users before hand.

Comment: You can make the original mesaure invisible. Then no body will see it unless they have special rights on the cube. So it is not really secured but hidden.